# How to get week number of the month by week number of the year

Tags: excel

I only have week number for the year. How can I get the week number of the month?
For ex:

Week
 42

Week of the month
2

How can I get the “2” in excel?

Comment: Try this formula =INT((6+DAY(E9+4-WEEKDAY(E9-1)))/7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a formula for you.

```
=INT( DAY( (A1-1)*7+ (DATE(B1,1,1)+ (8-WEEKDAY(DATE(B1,1,1),2))) ) / 7)
```

The formula is inserted in C1, year is present in B1 and week number is present in A1
Week numbers are according to ISO stranded.